# Как задать Индивидуальные переменные для каждого пользователя в боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, aiogram

**Вот эти переменные**

```
type.key = random.choice(list(type.words.keys()))
type.length = "-"*len(type.key)
type.wrong = 0
type.used = []
```

**Весь код**

***Bot.py***

```
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)

storeg = MemoryStorage()

bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN, parse_mode="HTML")
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storeg)

class Test(StatesGroup):
    Q1 = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'],state=None)
async def start_game(message: types.Message):
    type.key = random.choice(list(type.words.keys()))
    type.length = "-"*len(type.key)
    type.wrong = 0
    type.used = []

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
        fmt.text(
        fmt.text('ДОБРО ПОЖАЛОВАТЬ В ИГРУ ВИСЕЛЬНИЦА!!!'),
        fmt.text('======================='),
        fmt.text('Вы использовали эти буквы:', *type.used),
        fmt.text("Ошибок:", fmt.hbold(type.wrong)),
        fmt.text('======================='),
        fmt.text('Загадака звучит так:', type.words[type.key]),
        sep="\n"
    ), parse_mode="HTML")

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, fmt.text('Слово:', type.length))
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напишите "Отмена", если перехотели играть')
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите букву или слово')

    type.input_let_id.clear()
    type.bot_id.clear()

    await Test.Q1.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Test.Q1)

async def game(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        answer = message.text.upper()

        await state.update_data(Q1 = answer)

        if answer == type.key:
            type.length = type.key

        if answer in type.key:
            new = ""
            type.used.append(answer)

            for i in range(len(type.key)):
                if answer == type.key[i]:
                    new += answer
                else:
                    new += type.length[i]

            type.length = new

            if type.length == type.key:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, fmt.text("Вы победили!!! Загаданное слово было:", type.key))
                await state.finish()

                for i in type.bot_id:
                    await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, i)
                
                for i in type.input_let_id:
                    await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, i)

        elif answer != 'ОТМЕНА':
            type.used.append(answer)
            type.wrong += 1
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, HANGMAN[type.wrong])


        if type.wrong == len(HANGMAN) - 1:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, fmt.text('Вас повесили :('))
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, fmt.text('загаданное слово было:', type.key))

            await state.finish()

            for i in type.bot_id:
                    await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, i)
                
            for i in type.input_let_id:
                await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, i)

        elif type.wrong != len(HANGMAN) - 1 and type.length != type.key and answer != 'ОТМЕНА':

            msg = await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                fmt.text(
                fmt.text('Вы использовали эти буквы:', *type.used),
                fmt.text("Ошибок:", fmt.hbold(type.wrong)),
                fmt.text('======================='),
                fmt.text('Загадака звучит так:', type.words[type.key]),
                fmt.text('======================='),
                fmt.text('Слово:', type.length),
                sep="\n"
            ), parse_mode="HTML")

            input_let = await message.answer('Введите букву')

            type.bot_id.append(msg.message_id)
            type.bot_id.append(input_let.message_id)

        elif answer == 'ОТМЕНА':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Досвидание!')
            await state.finish()

    except:
        asyncio.sleep(0.1)

@dp.message_handler()
async def set_default_commands(dp):
    await dp.bot.set_my_commands([
        types.BotCommand("start", "Начать игру"),
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

***type.py***

```
import random

words = {"УРОКИ":"Что можно приготовить, но нельзя съесть?",
        "ШАХМАТИСТ":"Кто ходит сидя?",
        "ДВЕРЬ":"Кто приходит, кто уходит, все ее за ручку водят.",
        "ДОРОГА":"Если б встала, до неба достала б.",
        "ДЕНЬ":"К вечеру умирает, по утру оживает.",
        "РАДИО":"В Москве говорят, а у нас слышно.",
        "ВРЕМЯ":"Без ног и без крыльев оно, быстро летит, не догонишь его.",
        "ТУАЛЕТНАЯ":"Самая популярная бумага",
        "СЕКРЕТОМ":"Чем можно поделиться только один раз?"}

key = random.choice(list(words.keys()))
length = "-"*len(key)
wrong = 0
used = []
bot_id = []
input_let_id = []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `state: FSMContext` как в [примере](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/master/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py#L65):

```py
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram import types

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'],state=None)
async def start_game(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        ... # code with setting type_ variable
        data["type"] = type_
    ... # other your code
```

Comment: для чего это data["type"] = type_ ?

Comment: Это лишь пример. В вопросе `type` объект есть. Я в ответе указал `type_`, т.к. `type` в питоне - встроенный объект - его не стоит перекрывать